# Chef [version-13.0.17] - ERROR: Failed to post reporting data to server (HTTP 400)

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

After upgrading to chef server to v13.0.7. It is not showing any chef run reports on UI.

When checked logs on chef-client found following error

```
ERROR: Failed to post reporting data to server (HTTP 400), saving to c:/chef/cache/failed-reporting-data.json
```

Chef-server: v13.0.7
Chef-client: v15.1.36

Is there any workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef reporting is end of life since December 2018 and not compatible with chef-server 13 and chef-client 15.
More details here about each product: https://docs.chef.io/versions.html

With the latest move [Introducing the New Chef: 100% Open, Always](https://blog.chef.io/2019/04/02/chef-software-announces-the-enterprise-automation-stack/) Chef-server > 12 and chef-client > 14 are paid product only, which bring automate in the pack which is the replacement for manage/compliance and reporting.

If you moved to those version and have a commercial relation with Chef, contact Chef support for help getting automate setup. If you don't have a commercial relation with Chef, fall back to chef14 as client and chef-server12 or [goiardi](http://goiardi.gl/).

There's a community effort ongoing to provide a free-as-in-beer distribution of chef client 15 named cinc, as well as the other products from chef, you can find us in the community-distros channel on [Chef's Slack](https://community-slack.chef.io/) for Chef and Inspec ports and [Habitat's Slack](http://slack.habitat.sh/) for biome, the community version of habitat.